# How to insulate roof from heat (sunlight)

Tags: insulation, roof, heat

I'd like to insulate roof which is over my flat in 4 store building. MY flat is the last one and every summer is a killer for me as about for 1 month a year I have constant temperature of 30 Celsius. The roof is flat (actually 2% inclination) and currently covered with roofing felt.

I'm thinking about covering it with a layer of gravel or making a roof garden on it. Whole roof is about 100 square meters.

EDIT: one of comments led me to http://www.whiteroofproject.org/.

Comment: Do you own the building? Are you allowed to make these kinds of changes?

Comment: Don't insulate. Reflect. Think albedo.

Comment: I don't own the building but I can do such changes. How to make 100 or even 50 square meters of reflective area?